# Better to run 2 sql queries or 1 and deal with duplicate result set?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a webpage that has an ID as a `GET` variable that I need to pull the `name`, `city`, and `state` for that ID (stored in 1 table) as well as any data associated with it (stored in another table).

These are the results of a single query:

```
SELECT
    info.name, info.city, info.state,
    data.data1, data.data2, data.data3, data.data4
FROM
    data_table data,
    info_table info
WHERE
    data.id = 12345 AND info.id = data.id

name | city | state | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4
---------------------------------------------------
test | temp | AL    | 12    | 9     | 1     | 14
test | temp | AL    | 63    | 8     | 1     | 6
test | temp | AL    | 46    | 66    | 1     | 723
test | temp | AL    | 7     | 5     | 2     | 99
test | temp | AL    | 4     | 2     | 3     | 0
test | temp | AL    | 2     | 11    | 1     | 1
```

But the column data for `name`, `city`, `state` are all going to be identical for each row, so I could also do it with two queries and return the 'right' amount of data (but obviously taking twice as long to communicate with the server):

```
SELECT
    info.name, info.city, info.state,
FROM
    info_table info
WHERE
    info.id = 12345

name | city | state
-------------------
test | temp | AL
```

...and...

```
SELECT
    data.data1, data.data2, data.data3, data.data4
FROM
    data_table data,
WHERE
    data.id = 12345

data1 | data2 | data3 | data4
-----------------------------
12    | 9     | 1     | 14
63    | 8     | 1     | 6
46    | 66    | 1     | 723
7     | 5     | 2     | 99
4     | 2     | 3     | 0
2     | 11    | 1     | 1
```

So, in general, is it necessarily better to use 2 queries and returning the exact amount of data I need?  Or because of the (small) size of the data set being returned, just bite the dataset-larger-than-it-needs-to-be bullet and only run a single query?

I'm guessing that every situation varies, and if the `total server communication time / 2` > `time to transmit extra data`, then a single query is better?

Comment: It depends, but in general I try to minimize network communications to the client.  What I would do in this situation might either be two queries or one, but I minimize the data so there is nothing repeated.  It's pretty is to do with EF and Linq in the .Net world, I'm sure there is an equivalent in php.

Comment: One query that eliminates the duplicates as well according to whatever method you'd ordinarily use to handle duplicates in your code

Comment: There are some additional "costs" to consider: network latency to send two separate SQL text, cost of retrieving two separate resultsets, and the server overhead for parsing, preparing, and executing each statement, preparing metadata for each resultset, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid the pitfalls of premature optimization, and just do the single `JOIN` instead of trying to do your `JOIN` operations client-side.

If it later turns out that duplicated data is a significant strain, you have better options for addressing the issue besides doing multiple queries.

For example, [**result sets can be compressed**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/compression.html), reducing the the size of repeating data.  The CPU overhead for the compression would likely be substantially less than attempting to do `JOIN` operations client-side.

Comment: +1. A small amount of redundantly repeated data in a resultset is not normally a performance issue.

Answer (score 7):

For a small resultset, where the amount of redundant data is insignificant, use one statement.

One of the "hidden" costs (in terms of the MySQL server) is the overhead for each statement. Each SQL statement has to be sent to the server... MySQL has to parse and prepare each statement. MySQL has to check that a statement is syntactically correct (keywords, commas, etc.), that the statement is semantically correct, that is that the identifiers (table names, column names, function names) are valid, and that the user has permission on all of the objects). After that MySQL can produce an execution plan, evaluating different access paths (full table scan vs. using an index, the join order, and so on.

For a small resultset, it's going to be more efficient (in terms of the MySQL server) to send a single statement and return a few redundant columns, than it is going to be to process two separate statements and preparing and returning two separate result sets.

There's network latency involved in sending the query, and retrieving the resulset. So doing that two times is going to outweigh the cost of doing it just once, and sending a couple hundred bytes of redundant data in the resultset.

On the other hand, if the amount of redundant data is going to be significant, that's going to consume memory and network bandwidth, or, if the execution plan for the query is not as efficient as running two separate queries.... in those cases, running two separate queries is going to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your should consider 2 factors:

- cost of establishing 2 different connections
- network overhead of actually retrieving the data.

It all depends on your situation:

If each Id corresponds to thousands of rows, then the network overhead is higher to the cost of establishing 2 connections. So, it's better to break it down to 2 queries.

If each Id corresponds to a small dataset, the network overhead is lower than establishing 2 connections. So, it's better to just use one query.

What goes for your case, you must just see empirically which is faster.

Comment: I'd hope that OP isn't churning connections for each statement;  that's a performance killer of the first order. In terms of the extra costs for two separate statments, we need to consider the cost (in terms of network latency) for sending two separate statements, and two separate resultsets. In terms of MySQL server resources, there's the cost of the MySQL optimizer parsing and preparing an execution plan, and an creating a resultset to be returned.

Answer (score -1):

Your first query brings more load than you think. It loads two tables in memory and then filters the records with the WHERE clause. You better use a INNER JOIN to link two tables in one query.

I recommend two queries because this is a parent record with multiple children and you probably want to show the city or country and then a list of that other data.

Comment: The first part of this answer is nonsense. The comma _is_ an INNER JOIN operator. And for an INNER JOIN, it doesn't make a difference (to the MySQL optimizer) whether the join predicate is in a WHERE clause or an ON clause. The output from MySQL EXPLAIN will show that the execution plan is identical.

Answer (score -2):

You should just use one query, but use a JOIN to be sure you just get the data you need. This reference will show you how all the various types of join work.

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/